# Chaining promises to stop nesting

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise

Hi all I am trying to chain my promises.

my first https call gets back an array of urls. This works fine, what I then do is loop through them ( is there a better way to reduce nesting? ) and get back a json object for each one.

However I am having trouble being able to loop through the json objects because they do not seem to be in an array.

```
app.get('/start', (res, req) => {


    getUrls('https://json', 25, true)
        .then((result) => {
            let objects = [];
            result.forEach(url => {
                getJSONObject(url).then((obj) => {
                    objects.push(obj);
                });
            });
            return objects;
        }).then((objects) => {
            console.log(objects); // issue just shows empty []
        });
}, (err) => {
    res.status(400).send(err);
});




// this returns array of urls
getUrls = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(url, (response) => {
            response.on('data', (data) => {
                let parsed = JSON.parse(data);

                let newUrls = [];
                parsed.forEach((newId) => {
                    let newUrl = `https://item/${newId}.json`;
                    newUrls.push(newUrl);
                }, (err) => resolve.reject(err));
                resolve(newUrls);
            });
        }, (err) => resolve.reject(err));
    });
}



// this returns {} json object
getJSONObject = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(url, (response) => {
            response.on('data', (data) => {
                resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            }, (err) => reject(err));
        }, (err) => reject(err));
    });
}
```

Comment: where you `return objects` - it will be an empty array, of course, because asynchronous code needs to complete to add to `objects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in the first block of code

```
getUrls('https://json', 25, true)
.then((result) => {
    return Promise.all(result.map(url => getJSONObject(url)));
}).then((objects) => {
    console.log(objects); // issue just shows empty []
});
```